# Example of an element of the field $F_{2}[X]/({x}^{2} + x + 1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I find that $F_{2}[X]/({x}^{2} + x + 1)$ is an example of a finite ring with ${r}^{4}=r$, but i don't know what form are the elements of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can call them $0,1,\alpha,\alpha+1$, natural addition mod $2$. Multiplication is natural too, with the rule $\alpha^2=\alpha+1$. So $(\alpha+1)^2=\alpha$ and $\alpha(\alpha+1)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

When you mod out a polynomial ring by $(p(x))$, for $\partial p = d$, you end up with a representative of each coset being provided by each polynomial of degree $<d$.